# How to hide info button in ZBar Bar Code Reader for iOS6.0 and above

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, zbar-sdk

I am using ZBar Bar Code Reader for iOS 5.0 and above in my iOS App.

I have made info button hidden using following code on Camera Interface.

```
UIView * infoButton= infoButton = [[[[[reader.view.subviews objectAtIndex:1] subviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews] objectAtIndex:2];
[infoButton setHidden:YES];
```

But somehow this code doesn't work for iOS6.0 and Above.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this code, this worked for me on iOS5.0 and above.

```
float currentVersion = 5.1;
float sysVersion = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];

UIView * infoButton;
if (sysVersion > currentVersion)
   infoButton = [[[[[reader.view.subviews objectAtIndex:1] subviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews] objectAtIndex:3];
else
   infoButton = [[[[[reader.view.subviews objectAtIndex:1] subviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews] objectAtIndex:2];
[infoButton setHidden:YES];
```

**Explanation.**
    In iOS 6.0, If you print the log.

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[[[reader.view.subviews objectAtIndex:1] subviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews]);
```

Output.

```
"<_UIToolbarBackground: 0xa0991c0; frame = (0 0; 320 54); autoresize = W; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xa0795e0>>",
"<UIImageView: 0xa05d630; frame = (0 -3; 320 3); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xa05cfb0>>",
"<UIToolbarTextButton: 0xa0a8cc0; frame = (6 0; 60 54); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xa0a9460>>",
"<UIButton: 0xa0960e0; frame = (290 18; 18 19); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xa0615a0>>
```

in iOS 5.0, If you print the log.

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[[[reader.view.subviews objectAtIndex:1] subviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews]);
```

Output.

```
"<_UIToolbarBackground: 0x8d9df90; frame = (0 0; 320 54); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8dc12c0>> - (null)",
"<UIToolbarTextButton: 0x8de5ae0; frame = (6 0; 60 54); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8de5db0>>",
"<UIButton: 0x8d1b110; frame = (290 18; 18 19); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x8dba2b0>>"
```

**Hence for iOS 6.0 and above it should be object at index 3 since there is an extra view UIImageView**.

Comment: Note that on iOS 10 (at least on the beta version) it has changed again. Now the button is at `objectAtIndex:1` (vs. 3 for iOS 9 and below).

Comment: @Elad Thank you for the update will test it and update it shorlty.

Comment: I Think it changed again ? I'm trying to migrate an old cordova plugin and it doesn't works.

Answer (score 6):

With the last version of ZBar I solded this problem with another path:

```
UIView * infoButton = [[[[[reader.view.subviews objectAtIndex:2] subviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews] objectAtIndex:3];

[infoButton setHidden:YES];
```

The array keys are changed to [2] [0] [3]

Answer (score 3):

Try this code :

```
UIView * infoButton = [[[[[reader.view.subviews objectAtIndex:1] subviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews] objectAtIndex:3];

[infoButton setHidden:YES];
```

Comment: Isn't it the same answer given by icodebuster. you just copy-pasted it.

Answer (score 3):

Another hack.

*I didn't want to rely on only the views and subviews index, very prone to be changed.*
So I access the toolbar where the info button is inserted, and remove the appropriate `UIBarButtonItem`.

Create a subclass of ZBarReaderViewController:

```
@interface ZBarReaderViewControllerWithoutInfoButton : ZBarReaderViewController

@end

@implementation ZBarReaderViewControllerWithoutInfoButton


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // Accessing the toolbar
    UIToolbar *toolbar = [[controls subviews] firstObject];

    // Only keeping the first two items of the toolbar, thus deleting the info button
    if ([toolbar isKindOfClass:UIToolbar.class]) {
        toolbar.items = @[ toolbar.items[0], toolbar.items[1] ];
    }
}

@end
```

Do not forget to instantiate this new subclass (`[ZBarReaderViewControllerWithoutInfoButton new]` instead of ``[ZBarReaderViewController new]`) when presenting the scanner view controller.



Before:

[image: Before, with info button]

After:

[image: After, without info button]

Comment: Great...Thanxxxx.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the path to the button was a bit different, so here is my solution :

Get the button :

```
UIButton *cancelButton = [[[[[reader.view.subviews objectAtIndex:2] subviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews] objectAtIndex:2] subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
```

And hide it :

```
[cancelButton setHidden:YES];
```

Or do whatever with this button, I needed to translate it :

```
[cancelButton setTitle:@"キャンセル" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 2):

New solutions for new devices, as in iOS10 this Buttons its 2 instead of index3, here is the code with the before solution applied.

```
float currentVersion = 5.1;
float sysVersion = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
UIView * infoButton;

if (sysVersion > currentVersion && sysVersion < 10 )
   infoButton = [[[[[self.scanReader.view.subviews objectAtIndex:2] subviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews] objectAtIndex:3];
else
   infoButton = [[[[[self.scanReader.view.subviews objectAtIndex:2] subviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews] objectAtIndex:1];

[infoButton setHidden:YES];
```

Hope it helps, regards

Answer (score 1):

Not excatly what you asked for, but to remove the whole bar at the bottom of the screen you can use

```
reader.showsZBarControls = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code block.

```
float currentVersion = 5.1;
float sysVersion = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];

UIView * infoButton;

if (sysVersion > currentVersion && sysVersion < 10 )
    infoButton = [[[[[codeReader.view.subviews objectAtIndex:1] subviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews] objectAtIndex:3];
else
    infoButton = [[[[[codeReader.view.subviews objectAtIndex:1] subviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews] objectAtIndex:1];

[infoButton setHidden:YES];
```